# SLF4J not logging properly on remote machine

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, apache-commons-logging

I have a strange issue with SLF4J.

I have this logging configuration:

```
#####################
#  Loggers
#####################

log4j.rootLogger = INFO, LOGFILE
log4j.logger.ACCESS_LOG=INFO, ACCESS_LOG
log4j.logger.METRICS=ERROR, METRICS
log4j.logger.PERFORMANCE=INFO, PERFORMANCE

#####################
#  Log Appenders    #
#####################

log4j.appender.LOGFILE = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=/logs/logfile.log
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.maxBackupIndex=30

log4j.appender.METRICS = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.METRICS.File=/logs/metrics.log
log4j.appender.METRICS.maxBackupIndex=15

log4j.additivity.ACCESS_LOG=false
log4j.appender.ACCESS_LOG.File=/logs/access.log
log4j.appender.ACCESS_LOG = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ACCESS_LOG.Threshold = INFO

log4j.appender.PERFORMANCE = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.PERFORMANCE.File=/logs/performance.log
log4j.appender.PERFORMANCE.Threshold = INFO
```

and my java code:

```
private static final Logger acccessLog = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ACCESS_LOG");
private static final Logger metricsLog = LoggerFactory.getLogger("METRICS");
private static final Logger performanceLog = LoggerFactory.getLogger("PERFORMANCE");
```

Locally, this works as it should; there are four log files on my desktop with different information that is processed by different consumers. However, when I deploy this code to our production stack, the ONLY log file that's getting information is the logfile.log log. The other log files (metrics, access, and performance) all sit at zero bytes, even when I can make calls and validate that the application is processing events as it should. I do not know why, but it looks like for whatever reason, I can create and use multiple loggers locally with SLF4J, but in an environment that's not my local desktop, the whole thing fails and only one log file gets any data.

I'm using SLF4J version 1.7.12. This issue did not happen with apache commons-logging; it just started happening when I attempted to change our logging stack to use SLF4J over apache commons. Is there something wrong I put in my logging configuration that's causing this problem?

Comment: Why do you keep talking about using [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/), when you're using [log4j 1.2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) for the actual logging? --- Why tag it both `slf4j` and `apache-commons-logging`? Which facade API are you using? --- Why did you not tag `log4j` when that's the most important part of your logging setup?

Comment: What logging `.jar` files do you have in your app? Edit question and show them all.